# Download File, save it and read it again --> Error

Tags: node.js

I would like to download a file, write it to a temporary file, read it and give the readFileSync Buffer to a function. I tried this:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream("temp.pdf")
var request = http.get(linkArray[1], function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(data){
         file.write(data)
    }).on('end', function(){
         postData(fs.readFileSync('temp.pdf'))
    })
});
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't - my guess is that the file isn't written completely, when it is read. (But than the 'end' event shouldn't be fired ?!
As you can see, I would like to download a bunch of files and do this. Do you have any advise how to solve this? Maybe this isn't the best way to solve this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't link streams with `on('data'`  you should use pipe.  Pipe will link the streams data events to writes and end events to ends.

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream("temp.pdf");
var request = http.get(linkArray[1], function(response) {
    response.pipe(file).on('close', function(){
         postData(fs.readFileSync('temp.pdf'));
    });
});
```

also you should use https://github.com/mikeal/request

```
var request = require('request');

request.get(linkArray[i], function (err, response, body) {
  postData(body);
});
```

or

```
var request = require('request');
var file = fs.createWriteStream("temp.pdf");

request.get(linkArray[i]).pipe(file).on('close', function () {
    postData(fs.readFileSync('temp.pdf'));   
});
```

Comment: 'end' event isn't fired -> function postData isn't called, but the file is written

Comment: ahh, yes, sorry since it's a writable it's a close.  (pipe returns the stream being written to)

Comment: Hm, all of these versions lead to the same situation -> sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Comment: Are you using one temp file or a temp file per link?  You need to use one per link if you want things to run in parallel.

Comment: Ok, but if I use multiple files the 'close' Event isn't necessary - I need an Event when the download of all the files is finished or?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `file.end();` at the top of your `.on('end', ...)` handler.  The `end()` method itself is asynchronous, though, so you'll want to read the file once that's complete.  E.g.,

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream("temp.pdf")
var request = http.get(linkArray[1], function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(data){
        file.write(data)
    }).on('end', function(){
        file.end(function() {
            postData(fs.readFileSync('temp.pdf'))
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: This works fine, but if I surround it with a for or while loop (to go through the link array...) the request isn't send again - any idea on how to send multiple http.get requests