# Nodejs - Downloading and saving a PDF file yields empty, corrupt PDF

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to download and save a pdf file with nodejs and nightwatchjs, yet it does not work. PDF file remains empty (0kb) and I can't open it with Adobe Acrobat. Here's the code:

```
    var url = "http://www.sait.ca/Documents/sample.pdf"
    var file = fs.createWriteStream("form.pdf");
    https.get(url, function(response){
        response.pipe(file);
    });
```

It looks like this method worked for others (see -> [Download File, save it and read it again --> Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748232/download-file-save-it-and-read-it-again-error)), but it does not for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `stream.end()`.

Comment: The pleasure is all mine.

Answer (score 0):

Store the file in your public folder and do an redirect like this

```
res.redirect(http://yourdomain.com/uploads/your_file.pdf);
```